# Error on npm install pinkie-promise

Tags: node.js, npm

hi is there a way to install offline my dependencies, today I try to instal a new machine but the package pinkie-promise 2.0.0 is not available, (
When try to download direct from the site

https://registry.npmjs.org/pinkie-promise/-/pinkie-promise-2.0.0.tgz i get

```
{"error":"package could not be found."}
```

so the command  ´npm install´ get and error and rollback the process, i try to use the next versión the 2.0.4, and the command ´npm install pinkie-promise@2.0.4´ work and end success but, again run the command ´npm install´ to install all others and get the same error 404

Is there other way? i try to move the node_modules from other machine but the application dont work correctly